# Django: adding new field to the admin user in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to add a new char-field to the the django admin user. for that I have create new model  that extends ModelForm for models.py

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
    model = User
is_developer = forms.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and I edit the admin.py file.

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
form = UserAdminForm
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

when I try to run syncdb command it gives error 
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'.` what is the reason for that. Please tell me how can I add new filed to the Django admin user.give me some sample code or tutorials link.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Django Version you're using (<1.5 or 1.5) choose one of the two versions described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: This is not what I’m looking for. I need to add new field to django admin user , personal info part.ex: these is a default fields called First Name ,Last Name and Email. so I need to add another Extra filed to that. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: this is exactly what you're looking for. you need to define the field in a model in order for it to be stored in the database. just extending the AdminForm won't help.